# How do I prevent reset the select box after ajax post action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I want to make the option I selected fix to after AJAX POST.

Currently I am doing the work manually.

I put the value at OnChange in the HiddenField,

and after doing AJAX POST, re-insert the value selected in "ddlUserCont".

```
 <select id="ddlUserCont" onchange="ddlUserCont_Onchange(this);"></select>

 function ddlUserCont_Onchange(obj) {
    document.getElementById("<%=hidSelddlUserCont.ClientID %>").value = obj.value;
 }
```

-> After AJAX POST action..

```
 function btnTest_Click() {
 // ... Some logic

 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     cache: false,
     url: "../../WebServices/WebService.asmx/GetTest",
     data: jsonData,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data) {
         OnSuccess_GetTest(data, sTestVal);
     },
     error: function (request, status, error) {
         console.log("code:" + request.status + "\n" + "message:" + request.responseText + "\n" + "error:" + error);
     }
 });
 }

 function OnSuccess_GetTest(response, sTestVal) {

     var items = response.d;

     // ... Some logic

     var sSelPageName = document.getElementById("<%=hidSelddlUserCont.ClientID %>").value;
     document.getElementById("ddlUserCont_" + sSelPageName).selected = "true";

 }
```

Do I use UpdatePanel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is it getting reset? is the page reloading? or is some other script resetting it?

```
function OnSuccess_GetTest(response, sTestVal) {

     var items = response.d;

     // ... Some logic

     var sSelPageName = document.getElementById("<%=hidSelddlUserCont.ClientID %>").value; // get the value from the hidden field
     document.getElementById("ddlUserCont).value = sSelPageName; // set it on the select options element

 }
```

Just make sure that `select` has an `option` child element with `value=<sSelPageName>` at the time.

Comment: oh..I found my mistake. I initialized. Thank you for answering!

Comment: @cherryJang if this worked, please mark it as the answer or do post an answer yourself :)